# ByRef Type Mismatch when calling another sub

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to have a sub in VBA to call for another sub by passing the i value using the for loop. The problem is when u run the forLoop() sub, there is an error ByRef Type Mismatch. I am just trying out this example method to see if it works so that i can put into my bigger macro.

I tried to add the ByVal method but the error still remains. Someone please help me.

**The forLoop sub**

```
Public Sub forLoop()

 For i = 1 To 3

    Call Fetch_data(i)
    
 Next i
End Sub
```

**The Fetch_data() sub**

```
Sub Fetch_data(num As Integer)
    
    Dim data As String
    Dim myCellValue As range
    Dim myCellValue1 As range
    Dim sht As String
    
    Set sht = "mySheet" & num
    Set myCellValue = sht.range("J6")
    Set myCellValue1 = sht.range("J8")
    myCellValue1.Value = myCellValue.Value
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that

```
Sub Fetch_data(num As Integer)
```

is the same as

```
Sub Fetch_data(ByRef num As Integer)
```

so `Call Fetch_data(i)` gives `i` by reference. But since in `forLoop()` the variable `i` is not declared it is `Variant` by default and not `Integer` therefore the type mismatch. Make sure you use `Option Explicit` and declare all your variables properly:

```
Public Sub forLoop()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 3
        Fetch_data i
    Next i
End Sub
```

Also you can make the parameter `ByVal` as there is no need to have it `ByRef` (otherwise your sub `Fetch_data` could mess up the loops counter in `forLoop`:

```
Sub Fetch_data(ByVal num As Integer)
    Dim data As String
    Dim myCellValue As range
    Dim myCellValue1 As range
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("mySheet" & num)
    Set myCellValue = sht.range("J6")
    Set myCellValue1 = sht.range("J8")
    myCellValue1.Value = myCellValue.Value 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks you guys so much! Im new to VBA so im glad for all of your helps! Kudos.